# How to apply Custom coordinator behaviour to bottom navigation view

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, bottomnavigationview

I want to hide BottomNavigationView when page scroll. I found this code. I want to apply this to BottomNavigationView. How to find BottomNavigationView using Coordinator layout.

```js
class BottomNavigationBehavior  extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<BottomNavigationView> {

    public BottomNavigationBehavior() {
        super();
    }

    public BottomNavigationBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, BottomNavigationView child, View dependency) {
        boolean dependsOn = dependency instanceof FrameLayout;
        return dependsOn;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, BottomNavigationView child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, BottomNavigationView child, View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
        if (dy < 0) {
            showBottomNavigationView(child);
        } else if (dy > 0) {
            hideBottomNavigationView(child);
        }
    }

    private void hideBottomNavigationView(BottomNavigationView view) {
        view.animate().translationY(view.getHeight());
    }

    private void showBottomNavigationView(BottomNavigationView view) {
        view.animate().translationY(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
app:layout_behavior="path_to_your_custom_behavior_class"
```

to your layout xml code.